# How to 'manipulate' strings in BASIC V2?

Tags: basic, commodore

I would like to reach the following:
I ask for a number from the user, and then output a string like the following:

-STR$

--STR$

---STR$

----STR$

-----STR$

I tried to do this:

```
10 INPUT NUM%
20 FOR X=1 TO NUM%: PRINT NUM%*"-" + "TEXT" : NEXT
```

The code above got me an error: `?TYPE MISMATCH EROR IN 20`

However, I didn't yet figure out how to manipulate the string's beginning to multiply the '-' marks on each loop run

Comment: I edited my post by addig the code I tried to use. As it turned out it would be a too high-level solution because I got an error that says the following: "?TYPE MISMATCH EROR IN 20"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this:

```
10 INPUT NUM%
20 FOR I = 1 TO NUM%
30 FOR J = 1 TO I: PRINT "-"; : NEXT
40 PRINT " TEXT"
50 NEXT
```

There is no multipy of strings/character, as far as I remember to old (good) times.

Comment: It outputs one time only, and I want to output multiple times (see in question)

Comment: But now... sorry I missed that.

Answer (score 1):

I believe even older, more primitive forms of BASIC had the STRING$() function.  It takes two parameters:  the number of times to repeat the character and the character itself.  So...

```
10 INPUT NUM%
20 FOR X=1 TO NUM%: PRINT STRING$(NUM%, "-") + "TEXT" : NEXT
```

Comment: I'm still getting the type mismatch error in 20

Comment: It's been a while since I've coded in BASIC even though it was my primary language (I'm retired) but it's probably one of two things: Try replacing the plus sign (+) with a semi-colon (;).  If that doesn't work, it might be that I have the parameters backward for STRING$() so try STRING$("-", NUM%).  If STRING$ was not valid you'd be getting a SYNTAX ERROR instead, so it must be a valid function.

Comment: I don't think that the commodore BASIC (like many of the 6502 BASICs at the time) had the `STRING$()` function. It did have a `LEFT$()` though. An easy substitution: ` PRINT LEFT$("----------",NUM%); "TEXT"`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
100 INPUT NM%
110 BR$="----------"
120 PRINT LEFT$(BR$,NM%);
130 PRINT "TEXT"
```

This eliminates the need for an expensive `FOR` loop, and should be okay as long as `NM%` is not greater than the length of `BR$`.

One other thing to point out is that your variable names are effectively capped at two characters, e.g.:

> The length of variable names are optional, but max. 80 chars (logical input line of BASIC). The BASIC interpreter used only the first 2 chars for controlling the using variables. The variables A$ and AA$ are different, but not AB$ and ABC$.

(Source: https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Variable).  For that reason I used `NM%` instead of `NUM%`; it will prevent issues later.

Comment: If we care about efficiency, then we should not write 2 separate `PRINT` statements, but write `120 PRINT LEFT$(BR$,NM%);"TEXT"`. There's considerable overhead for every line in the program.

Comment: Absolutely true.  But because this is BASIC my view is that you would be better off writing for clarity, and then using a tool to compress it (or compile it).  "Make it work, then make it fast."